# How do I clean docker volume from the data that doesn't exist anymore?

Tags: postgresql, docker

I apologize in advance because I'm gonna name some things incorrect due to my lack of docker knowledge.

So I wanted to connect postgres database to my IDE pycharm.

I decided to deploy postgres image from docker hub and created docker container using this command:

```
docker run --name PSTGRS -p 5432:5432 -v /home/****/Desktop/pagila-master:/var/lib/postgresql/data  -e GRANT_SUDO=yes -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password postgres
```

using `-v` flag I have bound standard volume `/var/lib/postgresql/data` to some of my folder. I had some databases and tables in that folder and when I connected database to my IDE it worked fine.

But recently I have deleted my folder, postgres container, postgres image and all related volumes. I have used `docker prune volume` command and then made sure that no volumes left by using `docker volume ls` command.

The problem is even though I have pulled new postgres image from docker hub and created new container and bound volume to another empty folder, when I connect by database to my IDE it still show previous tables which don't exist anymore.

So my question is how do I fix it? How do I rid from those files that I don't even know where to find?

Thank you before hand!

Answer (score 2):

You've created a Docker [bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/).  Since the left-hand side of the `volumes:` specification is a complete path, the database files are in the host's `.../Desktop/pagila-master` directory.  They aren't managed by `docker volume`; you can delete these using the normal `rm` command (possibly requiring `sudo` access depending on ownership).

If you do want `docker volume` to manage these you need a [named volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/).  Syntactically this looks like a simple name with no slashes.  The storage will be inside Docker's local filesystem space and you shouldn't try to directly access it (almost can't on MacOS and Windows systems), which could influence your choice of which to use.

```sh
docker volume create pagila-master
docker run -v pagila-master:/var/lib/postgresql/data ... postgres
#             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ just the volume name
#                           not a complete filesystem path
```

```sh
docker stop PSTGRS  # the docker run --name name
docker rm PSTGRS
docker volume rm pagila-master
```

Comment: Hello! First of all thank you for such comprehensive answer. I did like you adviced, but once I connect to posrtgres yet again I see those tables, that I don't have anymore. Is there any change I can diagnose this problem somehow? Where should I look?